# Setting context for ES6 template literal within a Function constructor?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, template-literals

My app fetch a list of resources strings + placeholders tokens and it should change the token with a given value.

An example of such resource is : `"http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}";`

*(I get many like these in an array but that's not relevant).*

So now I have this^ string and I have the values. So I need to generate the digested string.

Sure  I can use `eval` :

```
var template = "http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}";
var name = "John";
var age = "30";
var url = eval(`\`${template}\``);
console.log(url); //http://example.com/?name=John&age=30
```

This works.But I don't want to use `eval`.

So I've switched to other approach of `new Function()()` :

```
var url = new Function ('tmpl','obj','return `${tmpl}`')
```

This yields the function:

```
ƒ anonymous(tmpl,obj ) {
return `${tmpl}`
}
```

So now I can do :

```
new Function ('tmpl','obj','return `${tmpl}`')(template ,{name, age})
```

But now I need to break apart `obj` within the inner function so that the template literal will know the values

BTW - I've tried this  - with no  success:

```
(new Function ('tmpl','obj','return `${tmpl}`').bind({name,age})) (template)
```

**Question**

How can I flatten `obj` in the inner function so that `${}` will have known local values?

Nb
I prefer not to go to regex solutions becuase of line breaks pros in template literals. and besides , those resources are intentionally in a format of es6 template strings

[**Online-demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fyjnnr?file=app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: You still have to eval to convert the string to a template. Using a function doesn't change that.

Comment: @KevinB the function returns a template "return `${tmpl}`"

Comment: Yes, but that's not going to do what you are asking for.

Comment: Your function doesn't even work. It just returns the `tmpl` as a string.

Comment: You're using template literal for something it wasn't intended for. This is why we still have template engines in ES6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper `new Function` replacement for your `eval` solution is

```
var template = "http://example.com/?name=${name}&age=${age}";
var makeUrl = new Function("{name, age}", "return `" + template + "`;");
var url = makeUrl({name: "John", age: 30});
console.log(url); //http://example.com/?name=John&age=30
```

Your function had just been returning the `tmpl` string that was passed into it.

Comment: Bergi - this means that I have to write each time the params part in  : `new Function("{name, age}"`.  ( different resources might have different tokens) ...Anyway to make it dynamic ?

Comment: Yes, you need to decide at some point which variables to make available. You could do `new Function("obj", "with (obj) { return `"+template+"`; }")`, but it's obviously not recommended. You can build the destructuring expression from whatever source you have available.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to solve this with template strings as I wanted .

```
setString(resource: string, obj: {}) {
    const names = Object.keys(obj);
    const vals = Object.keys(obj).map(key => obj[key]);
    return new Function(...names, `return \`${resource}\`;`)(...vals);
  }

var str = "We've sent your code to ${phone}.";
console.log(this.setString(str, { phone: 123 }))
```

**Output:**

> "We've sent your code to 123."

[**Demo**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ydygxw?file=app/app.component.ts)

Comment: So you don't want to use `eval`, but are OK with `new Function`? I hope you realise they essentially do the same thing...: parse a dynamic string as code at run time.

Comment: New function is not like eval. Eval has access to the local variable of my local method . Sure i could move eval to a seperate method but besides that  eval creates a new execution context whereas function not

Comment: Both parse a string as code at run-time, which is the major concern with `eval`: the same concern is applicable to `new Function`. That is my point.